# How to show github username on build job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins as CI for github project build. When a developer commit a changes that job will be triggered. I am using Pipeline view for viewing the build status. How can I put the developer github account name on the job view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Delivery Pipeline View](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin) Plugin to get the nice view and also various details like triggered cause, commit messages and etc.

[image]